# null parameter between two dates in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

I have a query as below :

```
select column_date, field1, field2, sum(field3) from table1
where field1 like '*xyz' and 
column_date between [please enter start date] and [please enter end date]
group by column_date, field1, field2
```

When I leave blank both the parameter boxes, the output is blank. But I want them in output as below

1. I want to display all records when I leave blank both  parameter box
2. if I put date in any one of the parameter boxes, it should display only records for that date
3. If i put dates in both the parameter boxes, it should display all records between those dates.

This is my asp code to display the output. It works when I insert values in both the text boxes but if I left blanks any of them or both, it shows error.

```
<html>
<body>
<%
dim startdate, enddate
startdate = Request.Form ("startdate")
enddate = Request.Form("enddate")
set conn = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "connectionname"
set rs = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
Sqlquery = "queryname '" & startdate & "', '" & enddate &'" "
rs.open sql, conn %>
<table>
<tr>
<%
For each x in rs.fields
response.write ("<th>" & x.name & "</th>") 
next %> </tr>
<tr><% Do Until rs.EOF %>
<% For each x in rs.Fields %>
<td>Response.write (x.value)</td>
<%next
rs.movenext %>
</tr>
<% loop
rs.close
conn.close %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I reckon you should be using a form to get your parameters: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-parameters-in-queries-and-reports-HA010096314.aspx#_Toc267474487

Comment: @remou. Thank you. You have given very useful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a plain SELECT query to figure out the WHERE clause.  Once you get that working correctly, convert it to a GROUP BY query.

So see if this one targets the correct records:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, t.column_date
FROM table1 AS t
WHERE
       t.field1 Like '*xyz'
    AND (         
       (t.column_date Between [Start Date] And [End Date])
    OR ([Start Date] Is Null And t.column_date = [End Date])
    OR (t.column_date = [Start Date] And [End Date] Is Null)
    OR ([Start Date] Is Null And [End Date] Is Null)
       );
```

Assuming that first query returns the correct rows, I think this GROUP BY query may give you what you want.

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT t.column_date, t.field1, t.field2, sum(t.field3)
FROM table1 AS t
WHERE
       t.field1 Like '*xyz'
    AND (         
       (t.column_date Between [Start Date] And [End Date])
    OR ([Start Date] Is Null And t.column_date = [End Date])
    OR (t.column_date = [Start Date] And [End Date] Is Null)
    OR ([Start Date] Is Null And [End Date] Is Null)
       )
GROUP BY t.column_date, t.field1, t.field2;
```

If running this query from classic ASP, you will need to substitute the ANSI wild card character `%` for the Access-style `*` wild card.

```
t.field1 Like '%xyz'
```

Or consider using `ALike` and the ANSI wild card instead of `Like`.  That way the query will always operate the same without needing to switch wild cards.

```
t.field1 ALike '%xyz'
```

Also, with classic ASP, run the query from an ADO Command object, and supply values for the parameters.

Comment: I have a problem executing this in asp.
when I write this sql code in access and try to simply just execute it in classic asp and leave both the text boxes(for parameters) as blanks, i get error. Is it because null parameters are not allowed in text boxes of asp or something else? Please note I'm very new to asp also. So I just would like to know if I'm making mistakes or it's not possible at all.

Comment: See updated answer. The classic ASP angle is important information which deserves to be part of your question. I added a tag.

Comment: @Hansup..I don't know about ADODB command object, I tried to learn more about the terms in Google but I could not understand properly. finally I tried with my known code updated in original question. It works well if I input values in both enddate and startdate text boxes. But If I leave them blanks, it shows error. Of course I changed the query as you advised  "alike '%xyz'

Comment: Thanks @Hansup.
But the example given in the link has fix value 15. Can you please give me an idea how can I modify it if I want to take those values from users in the form?

Comment: If your query parameter and your form field are both named "startdate", I'll guess: `objCmd.Parameters("startdate") = Request.Form ("startdate")`  If that's not it, you should open a question for this.  I'm not the right person to answer ASP questions.

Comment: Again thanks Hansup. It works now but just like the code I tried. It shows error when the text boxes are left blank. Anyway, I will open a new question for this. I'm happy for at least I can at least start using command object from now on. I didn't know about command object before.